# Editar item de un listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-listview

Quisiera saber como puedeo modificar un item x de un list view a traves de codigo del java...

Tengo la clase objeto Lista entrada:

```
public class Lista_entrada {

    private String textoEncima;
    private String textoDebajo;
    private String texto_id;

    public Lista_entrada(String textoEncima, String textoDebajo, String texto_id) {

        this.textoEncima = textoEncima;
        this.textoDebajo = textoDebajo;
        this.texto_id = texto_id;
    }

    public String getTexto_id() {
        return texto_id;
    }

    public String get_textoEncima() {
        return textoEncima;
    }

    public String get_textoDebajo() {
        return textoDebajo;
    }


}
```

la clase adaptador

```
public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int R_layout_IdView;
    private Context contexto;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> entradas) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView;
    }

    public Lista_adaptador( int entrada, ArrayList<Lista_entrada> datos) {
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }
        onEntrada (entradas.get(posicion), view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /** Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     * @param entrada La entrada que será la asociada a la view. La entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view View particular que contendrá los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada (Object entrada, View view);

}
```

en en mi actividad lleno la lista y la muestro:

```
datos.add(new Lista_entrada("BUHO", "Búho es el nombre","textol bla bla"));
        datos.add(new Lista_entrada("COLIBRÍ", "Los troquilinos","texto bla bla"));


        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_listado);

        lista.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(this, R.layout.entrada, datos) {
            @Override
            public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                if (entrada != null) {
                    TextView texto_superior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_superior);
                    if (texto_superior_entrada != null)
                        texto_superior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoEncima());

                    TextView texto_inferior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_inferior);
                    if (texto_inferior_entrada != null)
                        texto_inferior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoDebajo());

                    TextView texto_id_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
                    if (texto_id_entrada != null)
                        texto_id_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).getTexto_id());


                }
            }
        });
```

lo que quiero hacer es dada una posicion de un item en el listview, modificarlo solo a el, por ejemplo cambiar el nombre del item[0], Bhuo por Águila, por poner un ejemplo....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto es relativamente sencillo, agregué respuesta, pero porque modificar la lista de elementos original? @FelixAMarreroPenton

Comment: el problema es q yo nevego por ese listview hacia a delante y hacia detras, pero cuando vuelvo para atras puede ser q el usuario no sepa de donde salio, por eso mi objetivo es mostrarle como un marcador en el item del q salio,  yo tengo la posicion del item de donde salio guardada y entonces que cuando salga diga por ejemplo "salistes de aki"

Answer (score 4):

Esto se realizaría en el `Adapter`, pero primeramente debes modificar tu objeto `Lista_entrada` para que pueda modificar la propiedad :

```
 private String textoEncima;
```

agrega un setter:

```
public void set_textoEncima(String textoNuevo ) {
    this.textoEncima = textoNuevo;
}
```

Agregando este método en tu objeto, ahora dentro de `getView()` puedes encontrar si el texto es "Buho" y cambiarlo por "Aguila":

```
@Override
public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
    }
    /************************************/        
    if(entradas.get(posicion).get_textoEncima().equalsIgnoreCase("Buho")){ //encuentra Buho.
        //Cambia texto a Aguila.
        entradas.get(posicion).set_textoEncima("Aguila");
    }
    /************************************/

    onEntrada (entradas.get(posicion), view);
    return view;
}
```

---

**Actualización:**

Lo que requieres es que al dar click a una celda y abrir otra Activity, la descripción de esta en el layout contenga el texto: `"Usted salió de aquí!"` para esto simplemente obtén la referencia del resumen y modifica su texto al dar click en el elemento:

```
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mHolder.txtDescripcion.setText("Usted salió de aquí!");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre", entradas.get(position).getTexto());
            intent.putExtra("descripcion", entradas.get(position).getDescripcion());
            context.startActivity(intent);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Esta sería el método completo `getView()` :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate the layout.
        final ViewHolder mHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mHolder.txtTitulo=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            mHolder.txtDescripcion=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            mHolder.mImage=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.androidImage);
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);


        }else{
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        myObjeto item = entradas.get(position);
        mHolder.txtTitulo.setText(item.getTexto());


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mHolder.txtDescripcion.setText("Usted salió de aquí!");

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("nombre", entradas.get(position).getTexto());
                intent.putExtra("descripcion", entradas.get(position).getDescripcion());
                context.startActivity(intent);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        return convertView;
        //return convertView;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-ListView-WhereIComeFrom

Comment: el getView se implementa en el adapter o en la actividad

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón el método getView() lo debes tener en tu Adapter es un método requerido para su funcionamiento. En tu clase Lista_adaptador cambia el método que tienes por el que te doy, además agrega los cambios a tu objeto.

Comment: a ver si me explico, yo navego hacia delante y hacia detras en el listview y lo que quiero es por eljemplo que cuando vuelba atras ell usuario sepa el item de donde salio, yo tengo la posiscion del item de donde salio guardad y entonces que cuando salga diga por ejemplo "salistes de aki"

Comment: Bueno eso me parece no lo especificaste en la pregunta, pero bueno si tienes guardado ese item de donde salio? te refieres al indice?

Comment: Creo que ya entiendo por esa razón tienes  textoEncima y texttoDebajo? confirmame por favor. Para almacenar el dato anterior, si es así esto no es necesario!

Comment: si ams menos es eso, el valor de texto arriba esta lo que s emuestra en el item y en el valor de texto abajo pongo la alerta, por ejemplo "ustedes salio de aki"

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón en una celda del listView que es lo que deseas poner? el texto arriba abajo  o cual?

Comment: en la celda del lis view va  a salir el texto de arriba mostrando el texto que le corresponde a cada item(segun con lo q estoy llenando el lisview), el texto de abajo va a estar vacio = "", y cuando vuelva detras yo obtengo la poscicion del item de donde vine y quiero mostrar en texto abajo "salistes de aki"

Comment: Agregué actualización, si deseas el código del ejemplo entra a este repository: https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-ListView-who-is-entering

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56695/discussion-between-felix-a-marrero-penton-and-jorgesys).

Comment: ya edite la pregunta y añadi una imagen que s mas menos lo q quiero

Comment: Cuando agregas el mensaje? Cuando sales de donde?

Comment: por ejemplo, vistes la foto que le agrege a la pregunta...cuando presiono en  item 4 me va  a otra actividad y cuando doy atras me vuelve al listView y entonces quiero que muestre como esta en la foto que publique...debajo de item4 "usted salio de aki"...

Comment: Y es todo o hay otra consideraciòn?

Comment: mas menos esa es la idea

Comment: @FelixAMarreroPentón agregué en la respuesta un ejemplo completo en github.

Comment: descarge y funciona pero tengo que ver como lo adapto porque de esa forma creo q no me resuelve

Answer (score 3):

Teóricamente te alcanza simplemente llamar a `notifyDataSetChanged()` después de manipular datos en tu lista.

```
// despues de actualizar datos
BaseAdapter adapter = (BaseAdapter) lista.getAdapter();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Tu usas un VO (*value object*) para tus entradas, pero te reservas la opción de editar datos parciales. Eso solamente tiene sentido en un contexto multihebra. Asegurate que tienes presente que mientras editas valores que el objeto va cambiar así, así cuida tus referencias.

Como edición implica remplazar un VO con otro, la propuesta de solución sería agregar el siguiente método al adapter:

```
public remplazar (int posicion, Object remplazo){
    entradas.set(posicion, remplazo);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // aqui se inicia la actualisacion de la lista y sus vistas
}
```

fin TLDR;

Algunos consejos sobre tu código:

- Ponte más consecuente con estilo de código. Si usas `lista_entrada` o `listaEntrada` (camelCase es muy preferido en Java) en el fondo es cosa de tu gusto, pero tu código queda más claro si eliges uno y te quedas con eso.
- Si usas genericos, usalo bien, o dejalos completamente. Tu clase abstracta con genericos debería declararse como `public abstract class ListaAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter`, y consecuente se debería usar T en declaraciónes como `ArrayList<T> entradas;` y en métodos como `public T getItem(int pos){...})`.
- Tu usas un VO (*value object*) para tus entradas, pero te reservas la opción de editar datos parciales. Eso solamente tiene sentido en un contexto multihebra. Asegurate que tienes presente que mientras editas valores que el objeto va cambiar así, así cuida tus referencias.
- Si permites cambiar valores de un objeto con un id único, revisa si el patrón de VO es ideal para tu lógica.
- El adapter se llama adapter por algo: si lo usas, expone lo que necesitas para actualizar la lista dinámicamente y evita acceder la lista encapsulada directamente.

Comment: como llamo ese metodo en la actividad

Comment: Te dejé código en la respuesta. Sin embargo te recomiendo de implementar métodos en tu adapter incluyendo la llamada para la actualización (como en el segundo ejemplo de código).